# How to set Showheader to true or false in visualforce page based on profiles?

Tags: visualforce

I need to set the showheader property in visualforce page to true or false based on user profile. For all internal salesforce users the showheader property should be set to true and for all external/portal users the showheader should be set to false.

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" showHeader="true">
    <apex:detail relatedList="true" inlineedit="TRUE" />
</apex:page>
```

Comment: @Eystornt Using rendered attribute within apex detail section, can we set showheader property to true or false? For all profiles i need to display the same detail but only i need to change the showheader attribute.

Comment: Ha, my bad. I read that question too quickly ! Wait a second

Comment: @Eystornt Ok Sure.

Comment: Apparently you can use the attribute rendered on the <apex:page> tag. So you can do something like <apex:page standardController="Contact" showHeader="true" rendered="{!$Profile.Name == 'SomeProfileName'}">

Comment: From where users navigate to the page, can you write some condition over there?

Comment: @Rahul Sharma I have set this visualforce page as a default view page for contact object.

Comment: Overridden view button for object?

Comment: @Rahul Sharma Yes. Correct. If show header is set to true for all internal users it works fine but for external users when i click a contact i see another header within the vf page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `showHeader` attribute supports normal Visualforce expressions so you can reference Visuaforce globals like [$Profile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_profile.htm) or controller boolean properties.

For example, this will only show the header for SA users:

```
<apex:page showHeader="{! $Profile.Name == 'System Administrator' }">
Page content
</apex:page>
```

No need for 2 pages.